# Jenkins plugin advanced development

Tags: javascript, java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am trying to create an advanced feature in jenkins plugin but no idea where to start.

I wanted to create a table which has dynamically row added with checkbox in one column and get value of those selected checkboxes.

Please help me out for.
a) generate dynamically table.
b) add checkbox in column and get checked value.

Comment: If you haven't read official wiki pages, please start from here,https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial.

Comment: Yup ! That link provide basic knowledge but my question for advanced topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of RnD. Jenkins tag library not provided so much control but it has one control that make us happy.

`<f:block></f:block>`

In this block we can create a table or other html controls.

For dynamically created rows and coloumns we should use javascript in `<script />` tag it not requried type like in html.

Guys i tried jQuery but jenkin stapler not allow this, because sign of dollar is used for stapling classes in jenkin.

If you know the data for generating dynamic row then that's ok. but if your data is came from server side then we have to implement ajax functionality.

For ajax functionality in jenkins use this link.

"https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AJAX+with+JavaScript+proxy"